# Dismiss keyboard / number pad while in settings bundle iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, settings.bundle

I know the typical way of resigning the first responder of the keyboard with code, however I don't see anyway to do this is the settings bundle. Any ideas, or is this a bug?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Going through my iPhone, I don't even see any app setting bundles that use a text field. Seems like everyone is avoiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute any code in the settings app, you can only define what settings can be altered. If you want more control over settings then have them within your app, either manually or with something like InAppSettings kit.

Comment: Since the settings app is generated, would I be wrong to think that the return button of the keyboard would hide it?

Comment: I think it moves to the next enterable field. The settings on NetNewsWire do this (that's the only one I could find with a text field in, you're right they are quite rare!)

Comment: I guess ill keep all enter-able fields on the bottom of the bundle to avoid user confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You could group the text fields and place them into Child Pane. Then you can use the Back key to dismiss the keyboard. Better than nothing :)